Spell checking language in Microsoft Notepad using multiple languages
In Windows 11 Microsoft introduced a spell checker in Notepad (version 11.2402.18.0). According to some sources e.g. blogs.windows.com or elevenforum.com, it's supposed to be able to handle multiple languages.
However, my German Windows 11 Installation (23H2) doesn't process English words, and all of them are marked as mistakes. Regardless if the whole text or only part of the text is in English. Also, I only get correction suggestions with German words.
My first idea was changing the keyboard layout which helps with Windows speech recognition, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on Windows Notepad.
Note: Based on the suggestions: changing the language settings "Country or Region" and "Regional format" to English / United States had no effect. Restarting the System had no effect either. Using the following test sentences:
Hallo, wie geht es dir? Mir geht es gut, wie geht es Dir?
Hello, how do you doing? I'm doing well, how are you?
Bonjour, ca va? Ca va bien, et toi?

I get the following result (screenshot), with the English words being underlined as wrongly spelled:

Here's a screenshot of the current country and region settings:

Can anyone replicate this behavior or rather get the correct result using multiple languages? How do I make Notepad recognize English text in order to use the spell checker with the appropriate language?

Does MS directions for adding language pack for Office at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-or-change-the-languages-used-to-check-spelling-and-grammar-64bd812f-a301-478b-883a-32ee2223d42d help with the issue? Personally, I find LibreOffice installation makes the task of adding its language packs much simpler. sigh

@DrMoishePippik yes, I use Englisch spell and grammer check within Office 365

@Albin, BTW, use the English pack when checking English (und deutsches Sprachpaket für die Deutsche Sprache. ;-)

@DrMoishePippik Actually I'm using both with English at the top position (see newly added screenshot) - same result. The last thing I can think of is to change the "Windows display language".

You only need to add English as a second language in the Windows Settings. Here are the "Language"-settings I used, to get it to work:

Now German as well as English words are recognized (however currently I only get German suggestions to correct the spelling):

Any other settings, e.g. "Region" settings and the "Display Language", didn't help with the issue.
In my case, there was one additional issue:
The thorough reader might notice that I had similar settings already when I asked the question. Notepad's new function to restart old sessions got in the way: new settings don't apply to the "old instances" of Notepad that were opened already before changing the settings (even after restarting Windows). If you have similar problems make sure to start a new instance of Notepad, either in a new window or in a new tab.
